# WPF, c# datepicker in datagrid commit

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datepicker

I have problem with [DatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker?view=netframework-4.7.2) which is in [Datagrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=netframework-4.7.2).
When I change the Date in row which is created - visible is OK, but when I read the datas there is old value. I must go to another cell and pres Enter, after that is OK.

How to Commit the changes automatically? Which Event? I tried differents Events .. and [CommitEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindinggroup.commitedit?view=netframework-4.7.2), but nothing helps me for now.
Thank you

My XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg_work" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="142" Margin="11,396,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="927" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PreviewKeyDown="dg_work_PreviewKeyDown" AddingNewItem="dg_work_AddingNewItem" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Ident}" />
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Datum">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Datum}" BorderThickness="0" SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged" CalendarClosed="DatePicker_CalendarClosed" TouchEnter="DatePicker_TouchEnter" TextInput="DatePicker_TextInput" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Arbeitszeit-Beginn" Binding="{Binding VonP}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Arbeitszeit-Ende" Binding="{Binding BisP}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rüstzeit" Binding="{Binding Rzeit}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pause" Binding="{Binding Pzeit}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Übernachtung" Binding="{Binding Ubern}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Anfahrts-Zeit" Binding="{Binding ANZeit}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Anfahrts-KM" Binding="{Binding ANkm}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rückfahrts-Zeit" Binding="{Binding RFzeit}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rückfahrts-KM" Binding="{Binding RFkm}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Zusatzinfos" Binding="{Binding Zinfo}" />

                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

In C#:

```
        private void DatePicker_CalendarClosed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dg_work.CommitEdit();
    }

    private void DatePicker_TouchEnter(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        dg_work.CommitEdit();
    }

    private void DatePicker_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {

        dg_work.CommitEdit();
    }
```

Comment: Did you implement INotifyPropertyChanged to your model and call ProperyChanged() event in Datum's setter? If yes, set Mode to TwoWay and UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged in DatePicker's SelectedDate.

Comment: Where are you trying to get the value?